# Official data from census

Tags: data-request, census, demographics

I'm going to collect demographic data from official sources.

There is a list of census sites with informations like license, data format, granularity, direct links, languages, etc?

Will it be useful if shared or data aggregated?

Any other info that will be useful?

I'm going to do some edits to this post, or opening a page on some website (is it possible to make a table here anyway?). So I'm starting list here:

- Italy, csv and excel format, city granularity, english available, link: http://dati-censimentopopolazione.istat.it/?lang=en&SubSessionId=06184093-56c2-4f00-a62a-416c934fd65e
- New Zeland, Excel format, english language, link: http://www.stats.govt.nz/browse_for_stats/population/estimates_and_projections/historical-population-tables.aspx

Comment: https://international.ipums.org/international/samples.shtml has already done this and standardized each census microdata set.

Comment: @AnthonyDamico, you should think about turning that comment into an answer :)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for: "license, data format, granularity, direct links, languages, etc?"